# Getting the selected option value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to print the selected values of all selects using jQuery.
I did it like this, but I feel that there is a nicer way to write the same.
Am I right ?

```
$("select").each(function() {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

```
alert($(this).val());
```

jQuery's [`val` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will return the value of the selected option from a `<select>` element.